# What is a gasket head kit?

Tags: engine

I am looking at buying a used car, many listed have had "gasket head kit" installed?

1. What is a gasket head kit?
2. Should i be wary about buying a car with one installed?

Will the "gasket head kit" need maintenance over and above a vehicle with out one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An installed Gasket Head Kit means that the owner has replaced the gaskets that are needed when replacing the cylinder head. This could be a good thing (ie new parts) or a bad thing (why did they replace it)

Worth asking what the reasons were - standard maintenance, replacement for blown gasket (check for other damage) or non-standard replacement (different spec gaskets)